# Incorrect error showing up when trying to use PHP to enter info into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, input

I'm trying to create a PHP script to connect an HTML form to a MySQL database, and everything is working except there is one input that cannot be null, and no matter what I do, the system doesn't seem to recognize when I enter text into the field, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my PHP code:

```
if (empty($_POST['book_name']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the book name.';
}
else    {
    $booktitle = trim($_POST['book_name']);
}

if (empty($_POST['author']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the author.';
}
else    {
    $author = trim($_POST['author']);
}

if (empty($_POST['cover']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the book cover image.';
 }
else    {
    $cover = trim($_POST['cover']);
}

if (empty($_POST['publisher']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the publisher.';
 }
else    {
    $publisher = trim($_POST['publisher']);
}

if (empty($_POST['language_id']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the book language.';
}
else    {
    $languageid = trim($_POST['language_id']);
}

if (empty($_POST['length_pages']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the book length in pages.';
}
else    {
    $lengthpages = trim($_POST['length_pages']);
}

if (empty($_POST['fiction']))

{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter if the book is fiction or not.';
}
else    {
    $fiction = trim($_POST['fiction']);
}

if (empty($_POST['pub_year']))
{$errors[ ] = 'You forgot to enter the year the book was published.';}

else    {
    $pubyear = trim($_POST['pub_year']);

}

    if (empty($errors)) {
require ('mysqli_connect.php');


}

$q = "INSERT INTO books(book_name, author, publisher, language_id, length_pages, cover, fiction, pub_year) VALUES
('$booktitle', '$author', '$publisher', '$languageid', '$lengthpages', '$cover', '$fiction', '$pubyear')";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);



 if ($r) {
    echo 'Thank you! This book information has been entered into the database.';
}

 else {
    echo 'System error.';
    echo mysqli_error($dbc) . ' Query: ' . $q;
    foreach ($errors as $msg) {
        echo " - $msg<br>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

and here's my HTML code:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<p>Book name: <input type="text" name="book_name" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['book_name'])) echo $_POST['book_name']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Author: <input type="text" name="author" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['author'])) echo $_POST['author']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Publisher: <input type="text" name="publisher" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['publisher'])) echo $_POST['publisher']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Language:</p>
<p>English <input type="radio" name="language_id" value="1" /></p>
<p>Spanish <input type="radio" name="language_id" value="2" /></p>
<p>French <input type="radio" name="language_id" value="3" /></p>
<p>Italian <input type="radio" name="language_id" value="4" /></p>
<p>Mandarin <input type="radio" name="language_id" value="5" /></p>
<p>Number of pages: <input type="text" name="length_pages" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['length_pages'])) echo $_POST['length_pages']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Cover image file name: <input type="text" name="cover" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['cover'])) echo $_POST['cover']; ?>" /></p>
<p>Is this book fiction?:</p>
<p>Yes <input type="radio" name="fiction" value="yes" /></p>
<p>No <input type="radio" name="fiction" value="no" /></p>
<p>Year Published: <input type="text" name="pub_year" size="20" maxlength="100" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pub_year'])) echo $_POST['pub_year']; ?>" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></form>
```

And for whatever reason, every time I try to test it out, I get this error message:

> "System error. Query: INSERT INTO books(book_name, author, publisher, language_id, length_pages, cover, fiction, pub_year) VALUES ('', 'Not Hayley Munguia', 'Random House', '2', '134', 'howtobenormal.jpg', 'no', '1938') - You forgot to enter the book name."

even though I'm definitely inputting something into the book name field.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, all help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does the MySQL schema define the book name as `NOT NULL`?  In this case, then, you will need to always enter a non-null value or else (more painful) change the schema.

Comment: Yes it's NOT NULL, as it should be. The problem is that I am entering a non-null value but the system isn't recognizing the fact that it is non-null.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Please, don't suppress errors using `@`... if `mysqli_query` fails, and you're relying on it, your script should fail, too... especially when testing

Answer (score 0):

First check taking the sentences the mysql and put directly in the phpmyadmin and see the errors. Second I can see is likely the var book_name is empty